# Problems with updating ubuntu-core package on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

After I've ran `snappy update-versions` and `snappy update` I see follwing `snappy versions -a` output:

```
ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy versions -a
Part         Tag   Installed  Available  Fingerprint     Active  
ubuntu-core  edge  2          4          f442b1d8d6db3f  *       
ubuntu-core  edge  2          -          f442b1d8d6db3f  -       
webdm        edge  0.1        -          1604c8b7c9f6c5  -       
Reboot to use the new ubuntu-core.
```

After `reboot` I get:

```
ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy versions -a
Part         Tag   Installed  Available  Fingerprint     Active  
ubuntu-core  edge  2          4          f442b1d8d6db3f  *       
ubuntu-core  edge  2          -          f442b1d8d6db3f  -       
webdm        edge  0.1        -          1604c8b7c9f6c5  -
```

1. Anyone knows what's going on?
2. Did the update silently fail?
3. Where can I find some logs?